# Multi-leader or leaderless replication distributed DB (in-memory)

Tags: distributed, go, caching, redis

I am trying to find out few examples of multi-leader or leaderless distributed DB. It seems Redis is there but only enterprise version is having multi master support.

Any distributed DB which satisfy all (*at least most*) of the requirement?

1. **Multi-Leader or Leaderless replication mechanism.**
2. **Running in-memory** (*Good to have persistence storage also but not
   mandatory required*).
3. **Support for Golang client**.
4. Easy to setup.
5. Lightweight to run without consuming much resource.

I tried analyzing Dynamo style db - Cassandra, Riak, etc also but not sure how much requirement is aligned in them.

Highlighted ones are mandatory.